# Prismatic/Schema require key dependency?

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema, compojure-api

I am using [plumatic/schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema) with my [compojure-api](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api) to validate the input for an endpoint.

I have two keys in my schema: `Field1` & `Field2`. I want to be able to define a rule for my schema which for example says:

```
WHEN Field1 = "AA" 
THEN Field2 is required-key 
ELSE Field2 is optional-key
```

But, I only seem to only be able to set the key to either require or optional. Is it possible to make a key depended on another key?

```
(schema/def Field1
  (schema/enum "AA" "BB"))

(schema/def Field2
  (schema/enum "AAAA" "BBBB" "CCCC"))


(schema/defschema MySchema
  {(schema/required-key :field1)           Field1
   
   ; Here I want some kind of logic to make the key required if 
   (if (= Field1 "AA")
       (schema/required-key :field2)      Field2
       (schema/optional-key :field)      Field2)
   })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(use '[plumbing.core])

(schema/defschema MySchema
    (schema/conditional
        (fn-> :field1 (= "AA"))
        (schema/schema-with-name {(schema/required-key :field1) Field1
                                  (schema/required-key :field2) Field2} "cond1")
        
        :else
        (schema/schema-with-name {(schema/required-key :field1) Field1
                                        (schema/optional-key :field2) Field2} "cond2")))
```